# Ubuntu 18.04, laptop ASUS ROG GL503VD-FY108 - "win" key works as "scroll lock"

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout, asus

After update from 17.10 to 18.04 I remarked than I can't use <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

Everything was fine: shortcuts not changed, other buttons work properly.

When I looked in keyboard layout, I was shocked. When I tap <kbd>Win</kbd> key, lamp "Scroll Lock" turned on/off. It this normal?

Thanks for your answers.

Output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard` command

```
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru,by"
XKBVARIANT=",,"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:lwin_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output of the command `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thanks. I see that XKBOPTIONS contain link between win key and scroll lock led.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XKBOPTIONS` line in `/etc/default/keyboard` seems to be the culprit. So you'd better edit the file, and remove the `grp:lwin_toggle` option.

But it's likely that that option has been imported to the related desktop settings too. To deal with that you may want to run this command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```